# Simultaneous run of python loops from cron

Tags: python, loops, cron

I've a script with a loop for some minutes.
It starts at 9:30AM and it runs a loop (*time.sleep(120)*) and then re-execute the script) for a variable amount of time (max 2h).

Now I would like to run a second script (at the same hour) which does the same: starts a loop for a variable amount of time.

Will the 2 loops conflict? Can I run 2 loops of python3 at the same time or I need any particular command to run them as different processes (like the & in bash)?

Comment: Use [multithreading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/).

Comment: Sounds like you have two separate scripts. If so, I assume you can invoke them with two separate cron entries. If so, they are independent Python executions -- therefore, no problem and no need for you to implement threading or any other complications.

Comment: @FMc has the concise answer to this question without requiring a refactor and why I came here. "Will the 2 loops conflict? Can I run 2 loops of python3 at the same time?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `threading` module. The following executes `print_cube` and `print_square` simultaneously.

```
import threading 
  
def print_cube(num): 
    """ 
    function to print cube of given num 
    """
    print("Cube: {}".format(num * num * num)) 
  
def print_square(num): 
    """ 
    function to print square of given num 
    """
    print("Square: {}".format(num * num)) 
  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # creating thread 
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_square, args=(10,)) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=print_cube, args=(10,)) 
  
    # starting thread 1 
    t1.start() 
    # starting thread 2 
    t2.start() 
  
    # wait until thread 1 is completely executed 
    t1.join() 
    # wait until thread 2 is completely executed 
    t2.join() 
  
    # both threads completely executed 
    print("Done!")
```

You can also use `apscheduler`, but it will run the processes separately.

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

# Start the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

# Schedule job_function to be called every two hours
@sched.interval_schedule(hours=2)
def job_function():
    print ("Hello World")

    time.sleep(120)
    print ("my second script")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I don't need to create another script that runs the other scripts, but I'm wondering if the two script will run normally if launched from cron. If Python/Cron can't manage for 2 script running together I can create another script, but I would prefer not to do that

Comment: That's why the first method I wrote is best and suggested. It can handle and run 2 scripts normally. If I helped to solve your problem, please mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said, you can simply write two python scripts and create two cron jobs. Cron will manage this well and you're free from all the multiprocessing/multithreading hassles.

If you insist to write one script for only one cron job, in Python 3.2+ you have `concurrent.futures` that can make your life easier without worrying about all start and join:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def worker(n, sleep, count):
    for _ in range(count):
        print(n)
        time.sleep(sleep)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    # run 60 interations of print with 120 seconds sleep, total 2 hrs
    futures = {executor.submit(worker, n, 120, 60) for n in [1,2]}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        pass  # in case you need to read anything from each future object
```

This works if you do not have too many threads.

Comment: Yes, I already have the 2 scripts ready and I'm just wondering if I can run them together. E.g. run the 1st script at 9.30 and the second at 9.31. If the first starts the loop, the second will be blocked or it will run normally?

Comment: depends, due to python GIL. Threading is not so intuitive in python. If not sure, you can replace ThreadPoolExecutor with ProcessPoolExecutor, which you will guarantee not bounded by GIL but your OS will manage concurrent processes